# C# .net core reinit Oracle's session after expire_time

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

WebApi project on .net core (C#) use `System.Data.OracleClient` by `dotNetCore.Data.OracleClient` (Unofficial Oracle Client for .Net Core) Nuget's package (maybe it's important)

In webapi I call stored procedures from Oracle, e.g.:

```
string cs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_CS");
  using (DbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cs)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
      command.CommandText = "sp_check";
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      connection.Close();
    }
}
```

DB Oracle's parameter sqlnet.expire_time set to 3 minutes

When I call sp in first time - it's work well, and also work when I call one more times if it will be not later than 3 minutes
But if I call procedure after 3 minutes after called last one, I've got exception

```
RA-03135: connection lost contact
Process ID: 83002
Session ID: 450 Serial number: 7747
```

If I try to call one more time I've got exception

```
ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE
```

I understand that session expired, but I've open the connection every time when I want to call procedure. I also heard that when I do `connection.Open()` that doesn't make new session every time and just use old one.

How to be? How can I init new Oracle's session when I've got an exception that session expired?

P.S.: this problem happened when I run in debug configuration when I run on release configurations this work every time without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable connection pooling

Comment: Like this + "User Id=myusername;Password=mypass;Pooling=False;"; ?